В Moodle не работаю видеоконференции (BigBlueButton)
Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой работы видеоконференций (BigBlueButton) в экосистеме Moodle.
Не так давно я обновил версию плагина BigBlueButton до 3.0.7 и заметил, что в некоторых курсах не работают видеоконференции. Перепробовал все и не знаю в чем может быть проблема. Жду от вас интересных способов решения :D
Возможные подсказки:

В некоторых курсах, которые ранее были скопированы/созданы появились проблемы с видеоконференциями. При присоединении к сеансу перенаправление идет на страницу настроек плагина BigBlueButton.
Когда проект запускается на локалке с пустой папкой dataroot, данная проблема исчезает и все работает в этих курсах прекрасно.
При просмотре логов нет ни каких намеков на ошибки, а в логах BitBlueButton есть отсылки, что были попытки подключения к сеансу.
С данными и id записей, которые хранятся в базе, все хорошо.

Пока вот такие у меня розыскные работы были проведены. Не знаю в какую сторону уже думать. Надею, что вы мне поможете.
--- Спасибо!
